# how do i reference a class library that contains entity framework?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I am trying to create a reusable class library that is a database first entity framework project.  the projects sole purpose is to be a container for entity framework.  The project successfully builds, and i was able to run a simple unit test proving i could write to the database with the project.  when i reference the dll of the EF project in another project(**Project B**), I am unable to write to the database. i get the following error

> Unable to update the EntitySet 'foo' because it has a DefiningQuery
>   and no  element exists in the
>    element to support the current
>   operation.

I have also discovered that i must provide a connection string for the EF project in project B's config file so that the application will build.

**Is there a way to diagnose if my problem is related to the connection string?**
if the issue does not stem from the connection string, where else can start in the path of diagnosing the issue?

foot notes:
I have installed entity framework 4.2 in both projects.
i have mirrored the connection string between EF project and Project B
when i had a single solution containing project B and ef project, i was able to write to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a view referenced in your edmx?

If so you need to tell EF that it is not updateable, it is not able to detect it normally.

Comment: foo is a table, not a view.  I believe i have some views in my edmx file, but those should be affecting foo?